How do father’s who bless their sons in the Bible know what will happen in the future? Or is it figurative speech?
There are many blessings in the word both positive and negative. For the sake of shortening the question I will use Genesis 49:8-13
8  Judah,[b] your brothers will praise you;
your hand will be on the neck of your enemies;
your father’s sons will bow down to you.
9  You are a lion’s cub, Judah;
you return from the prey, my son.
Like a lion he crouches and lies down,
like a lioness—who dares to rouse him?
enter preformatted text here
10  The scepter will not depart from Judah,
nor the ruler’s staff from between his feet,[c]
until he to whom it belongs[d] shall come
and the obedience of the nations shall be his.
11  He will tether his donkey to a vine,
his colt to the choicest branch;
he will wash his garments in wine,
his robes in the blood of grapes.
12   His eyes will be darker than wine,
his teeth whiter than milk.[e]
13  Zebulun will live by the seashore
and become a haven for ships;
his border will extend toward Sidon.
How did Jacob know all these things would come to pass such as where Zebulun would live? Are these things revealed to him, is it just what his heart desires or is it figurative speech?

I just asked a simple question. I’m not trying to apply anything. Like I said there are manyyy not just Jacob, I used his as an example. Not every single father who gave a blessing was a prophet thus the words “happen in the future” not sure where you got fortell from, & you can always reword questions if you like! Thank you for your answer —it answers Jacob’s case specifically. I accept all answers. I’m here to learn. Thanks

Jacob was an inspired prophet of God who revealed this information via the Holy Spirit, see 2 Peter 1:19-21, 2 Tim 3:16, 17.

I’m actually not quite sure why I’d have to look this up. Yes, Jacob was a prophet. Yes, I understand why he said what he said…so again not sure about this random comment. Jacob was only the example in this question. There are many father’s who blessed their sons who were not prophets. Simple.

God of ProvidenceGod Almighty is a God of providence. As some scholars have coined it, "He is an over-arching Superintendent," or "the Governor of the Universe," or the " the Lord from everlasting to everlasting" (Psalm 90:1-4).
And the Psalmist also remarked:

O LORD, Thou hast searched me, and known me. Thou knowest my downsitting and my uprising, Thou understandeth my thought afar off. Thou compassest my path and my lying down, and art acquainted with all my ways. For there is not a word in my tongue, but Lo, O Lord, thou knowest it altogether. (Psalm 139:1-4)

God knows the future of human lives even before they are born (v. Psalm 139). So when we keep in mind that, in the Bible, we have the revealing of the "redemptive history " of God's salvation, and that the people---main players---in that drama are part of God's planning, it is not to be wondered that the destiny of those men are known---and that their birth names will reflect this!
Believing Parents The parents who are given to serving and worshipping the true God, are also gifted with the ability to know the Spirit and Voice of God, and be influenced by what they should do, including the naming of their children.
Sometimes the parents are aware of the implications of the name they give to their children by "inner whispers" of the Spirit.  Other times a visible Angel clearly and openly declares the names. (Note John the Baptist, and the naming of Jesus.(Gospel of Luke).
The prophecies given over the children of Jacob are not uncommon. God's prophetic word over people's lives is a common thread throughout the Bible.(Recall the prophecy over the Apostle Paul's life and ministry by Ananias; Acts 9). AND many charismatic Christians would aver that God still speaks into families' lives, and directs their destinies---and the destinies of their new-born children.
God is a God of Providence who knows the End from the Beginning.
